# looking up user form based between dates data from mysql for performing calculation in python

Tags: python, html, mysql, forms, sqlalchemy

I have been trying to look up a float value from mysql through python based on difference in two dates from form input

data is to be retrieved from third column of mysql table "rates". First and Second column contain days lets say 0-180 and difference in date from web form (flask) will pull the Rate data (third column) as per the condition.Thank you in advance for any help

python as following:

```
@app.route('/calculate',methods=['POST','GET'])
def submit():    
    if request.method=='POST':        
        settlementdate=str(request.form['settlementdate'])
        maturitydate=str(request.form['maturitydate'])
        investmentamount=str(request.form['investmentamount'])
       
        d1 = datetime.strptime(settlementdate, "%Y-%m-%d")
        d2 = datetime.strptime(maturitydate, "%Y-%m-%d")
          
        maturitydays=(d2-d1).days
        
        brokeragerate = Interbankbrokerage.query.filter(Interbankbrokerage.fromdays <=  
        maturitydays,Interbankbrokerage.todays >= maturitydays)
                      
        brokerageamount=round(investmentamount * brokeragerate/365 * maturitydays/100)
                           
        res=""
   
    exp12={'Brokerage Rate %':(brokeragerate)
         }   
    
    return render_template('placements.html',brrate=exp12)
```

Comment: I don't see any SQL statements, so is `[mysql]` relevant?

Comment: is it possible to modify this query "brokeragerate = Interbankbrokerage.query.filter(Interbankbrokerage.fromdays <=  
        maturitydays,Interbankbrokerage.todays >= maturitydays)" so that it returns value from a single column (rate) and not the complete row ? table name is "Interbankbrokerage", and it has three columns 1) fromday 2)today and 3)rate. Only want to have value returned from "rate" column so to use it in calculation? Thank in advance

Comment: got the answer. flask sqlalchemy documentation helped "https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/queries/#querying-records"

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL.  (I don't know sqlalchemy, nor the 99 other tools that 'simplify' access to MySQL.)

Comment: brrate = Interbankbrokerage.query.filter(Interbankbrokerage.fromdays <= maturitydays,Interbankbrokerage.todays >= maturitydays).first() brokeragerate=float(brrate.rate) ========> HERE 'Interbankbrokerage' is table, fromdays and todays are columns, 'rate' is another column which returns the value in it meeting condition as( fromdays<= maturitydays >= todays)

Comment: @Rick James: even your showing interest in it further motivated me. So thank you